# Can an Android layout XML file contain only rows?

Tags: android, xml, layout, tablelayout

I'm not sure if this is an XML question or an Android question.  I have a structure of XML that repeats in different layouts, so I want to extract it and keep it in its own file. It contains 3 rows of a TableLayout. I'm getting an error in the XML file. Any idea why? It is because there is no outer XML layout?

Thanks!

This is the content of the new xml file, which I later insert (via include layout) into the main layout file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableRow
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_calc"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/title_res"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/res"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_res_etc"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: How are you referencing this file? Also have you read http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html ?

Answer (score 1):

All your tablerows should be inside table layout. Here is andriod tutorial on how to use table layout.[Android table layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)

Comment: Even if I'm including them inside a TableLayout? The base layout file contains the TableLayout, and this xml file will be included ie <include layout="@layout/result_rows" />

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it should still work even you include this in another layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ViewGroup` as Parent Layout to contain multiple `View` inside it.
subclasses of `ViewGroup` are used to manage Layout
some of the subclasses are

```
LinearLayout
RelativeLayout
FrameLayout
TableLayout
```

and so on

so to have multiple `View` in a single layout, you should wrap all the views within any layout i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_calc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <!--Other views goes here-->
</LinearLayout>
```

and if you want to show `TableRow` it should be wrapped inside a `TableLayout` otherwise your `LayoutParams` is not applied to `TableRow`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there are only rows. The columns work by looking at the first item in each row, and making a column out of it.

As to why your code isn't working, you need to wrap it in a TableLayout. If you do that, it should work fine.

Comment: Even if I'm including them inside a TableLayout? The base layout file contains the TableLayout, and this xml file will be included ie <include layout="@layout/result_rows" />